# Sieve of Eratosthenes loop not correctly pulling elements

Tags: python, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm using a Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm that involves pulling the first element from a list, adding it to a list of primes, and then pulling out any multiples of that number from the original list (so starting at 2, append 2, remove all multiples of 2).  Then on to the next number.

My loop (in a test run on a list of 2-10) does what it's supposed to the first time around, but instead of pulling 3 the next time, it jumps straight to 5 and I'm left with a list of 2, 5, and 9.  Here is my code.

```
list_before_primes = [num for num in range(2, usr_in + 1)]
print(list_before_primes)
list_o_primes = []

for element in list_before_primes:
    list_o_primes.append(element)
    for sub_element in list_before_primes:
            if sub_element % element == 0:
                list_before_primes.remove(sub_element)

print(list_o_primes)
```

Comment: Unexpected things can happen when you change the size of a list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: So my logic looks sound?  If that's the case then I'll re-work the algorithm.

Comment: you have a but in your code. element and sub_element are same in the first iteration. So `sub_element % element == 0` will always return `True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you modify the `list_before_primes` inside the loop, you shouldn't use `for element in list_before_primes:` (as noted by @Kevin).

You can use a `while list_before_primes:` instead and pop the first item into `element`.

This will also solve @Kashyap Maduri remark (since the element will be removed from the list).

btw, you can simplify `list_before_primes = [num for num in range(2, usr_in + 1)]` with `list_before_primes = list(range(2, usr_in + 1))`

Comment: In Python 3, `range` returns a generator and not a list. But `list(range(2, usr_in + 1))` works just as well and is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of the algorithm:

```
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(usr_in):
    #you don't need list comprehension in your implementation. You can do this:
    list_before_primes = range(2, usr_in + 1)
    print(list_before_primes)

    #makes a set of list_before_primes
    #funny things can happen when you modify and iterate over the list at the same time. 
    #it is better to make a copy and remove from it.
    list_o_primes = set(list_before_primes)

    for i,element in enumerate(list_before_primes):
        for sub_element in list_before_primes[i+1:]:
            if sub_element % element == 0:
                if sub_element in list_o_primes:
                    list_o_primes.remove(sub_element)

    print(list_o_primes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sieve_of_eratosthenes(10)
```

Comment: This seems incorrect: `for i,element in enumerate(list_before_primes)` : you are going to test every element between 2 and n (when you should only test the elements that weren't removed)

Comment: that is why I have `if sub_element in list_o_primes:`. Not the most optimal code but it works.

Comment: I have explained everything in the comments fyi. I am adding an implementation based on the coments.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to downvote the answer though. I provided an implementation of solution with the comments. And explained the idea of **copying a list** in the code which will be useful for poster.